# ¿Cómo generar un código aleatorio con números y letras en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy intentando crear una app que me genere un número aleatorio con letras incluidas tipo matricula de coche con una longitud de 8 caracteres y números positivos. De momento he conseguido esto mirando guías y demás, pero ya no sé como avanzar. ¿Sabrían como puedo solucionarlo? Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
TextView my_code;
Button generate_code;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    my_code = findViewById(R.id.my_code);
    generate_code = findViewById(R.id.generate_code);

    generate_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int num = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(+ 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                if (i < 4) {
                    num += rnd.nextInt(8);
                } else {
                    num += (char) (rnd.nextInt(91) + 65);
                }
            }
            my_code.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num))));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida ¿Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código no funcionaría, ya que solo podría obtener caracteres numéricos.
Para obtener el código usa una variable de tipo String, esto para que puedas concatenar los caracteres (`num`). Para obtener los valores tipo String a partir del `char`, debes convertir a String, de otra forma solo obtendrías valores de tipo entero, realiza el siguiente ajuste:

```
generate_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        /*-----------------------------------*/   
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String num ="";

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (i < 4) { //Obtiene los primeros 4 numeros.
                num += rnd.nextInt(8);
            } else {
                //Obtiene caracter aleatorio entre 65 y 90 ("A" y "Z").
                num += String.valueOf((char) (rnd.nextInt(90-65) + 65));
            }
        }
        /*-----------------------------------*/

        my_code.setText(num);
        }
    });
```

Prueba [**el ejemplo aquì**](https://ideone.com/EHx9HM)

---

**Generar un código alfanumerico**

**Metodo 2.** Te sugiero usar la clase [**UUID**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID) que, como podrías suponer, genera un "Identificador Universalmente Único", por lo tanto, sería improbable tener colisiones por códigos repetidos.

Ejemplo:

```
 //Obtiene código alfanumerico de 8 caracteres.
  String num = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 7).toUpperCase();
```

Esto lo aplicarías en tu código:

```
generate_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*Random rnd = new Random();
            int num = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(+ 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if (i < 4) {
                    num += rnd.nextInt(8);
                } else {
                    num += (char) (rnd.nextInt(91) + 65);
                }
            }*/

            String num = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 7).toUpperCase();
            my_code.setText(num);

        }
    });
```

---

**Método 3.** Otro método puede ser usando la clase [**Random**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), para esto debe definir los caracteres que podría obtener aleatoriamente:

```
int lenght = 8;
String num = new Random().ints(48, 122) //Caracteres entre 0 a "z"
        //Establece filtro:  i < 58 : 9 y menor || i > 64 : mayor que "A" && i < 91 : menor que "Z" || i > 96 mayor que "a"
        .filter(i -> (i < 58 || i > 64) && (i < 91 || i > 96)) // Entre 9 a "A" y "Z" a "a"
        .limit(length).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString().toUpperCase();
```

Esto lo aplicarías en tu código:

```
generate_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         int lenght = 8;
         String num = new Random().ints(48, 122) //Caracteres entre 0 a "z"
         //Establece filtro:  i < 58 : 9 y menor || i > 64 : mayor que "A" && i < 91 : menor que "Z" || i > 96 mayor que "a"
        .filter(i -> (i < 58 || i > 64) && (i < 91 || i > 96)) // Entre 9 a "A" y "Z" a "a"
        .limit(length).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString().toUpperCase();

            my_code.setText(num);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tvMatricula;
private Button btGenerar;

private char[] letras = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
                         'Ñ', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
};

private int[] numeros = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvMatricula = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMatricula);
    btGenerar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btGenerar);

    btGenerar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String generado = generarMatricula();
            tvMatricula.setText(generado);
        }
    });
}

private String generarMatricula(){
    String matricula = "";

    //Generamos 4 números aleatorios
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        int posGenerada = (int) (Math.random() * (numeros.length));
        matricula = matricula + numeros[posGenerada];
    }
    matricula = matricula + " ";
    //Generamos 3 letras aleatorias
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        int posGenerada = (int) (Math.random() * (letras.length));
        matricula = matricula + letras[posGenerada];
    }

    return matricula;
}
```

}

Funcionamiento simple: cuando se pulsa al click del boton se genera una posicion aleatoria 4 veces de nuestro array de números, añadimos el espacio despues de esto (me he basado en las matrículas para hacer esto) y por último generamos 3 posiciones aleatorias de nuestro array de letras.